# Limit what classes can extends another class

Tags: php

I'm currently writing a solution that contains some abstract classes. One of these should only be extended from a few other classes as using it from other places than intended could cause a little bit of a mess. So what I want to do is limit what classes can extend this class.

So if I have a class named ImportantStuff which is abstract I want to say that only Class A and Class B are able to extend it while any other class can't.

You might wonder why I would want to do something like this. Well the code is written for work so there will be lots of other programmers working with it later, so I wish to make it clear for those that this class is not intended to be used from any other places than it already is. Yes I know I can write it in a class description and I have, but I want to make it 100% clear by blocking it as not all programmers are good at reading comments:) Also I'm kinda curious if it can be done in a good fashion as I couldn't find a good answer on the web.

So my question is: what is the **best** way to make this happen? I guess I can send a key or something that is handled in the constructor, but is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Limiting what classes may extent another class somewhat violates the [Open/Closed Principle](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Open/closed_principle). Whenever you want to allow a new class to extent the abstract class, you have to touch the abstract class and the new class. That's less maintainable. Also,  
I am curious. What kind of a mess are you expecting? This sounds rather like coding around a design flaw in your application.

Comment: @Gordon You got a good point there, might be bad practice to lock a class like that. "making a mess" might have not been the best choice of word, it's more that I don't want functionality that's meant for the core "misused" in applications written later. I'm trying to keep a seperation between resources intended for the core only and resources usable for building applications. But then again, not sure blocking it might be the best way to do that. Maybe I should just trust that everyone reads the documentation:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hmmm, make the constructor final (but add an init function) and check there which class is currently constrcuted, thats possbilie, but requires at least php 5.3

```
    abstract class bigOne{
        private $_allowedClasses = array('smallOne');

        final public function __construct() {
            if(!in_array(get_called_class(), $this->_allowedClasses)){
                throw new Exception('can not extend to Class: ' . get_called_class());
            }
            $this->init();
        }

        abstract public function init();
    }

    class smallOne extends bigOne{
        public function init(){

        }
    }

    class badOne extends bigOne{
        public function init(){

        }
    }

    $oSmallOne = new smallOne();
    $obadOne = new badOne();
```

Comment: This works great, thanks:) Only note is like sexyprout points out in his answer, it's for PHP 5.3+ only

Comment: yeah it is, sorry forgot to mention it (hey its out since june 2009 - time we start using it) and I wouldn't know an elegant way to do it otherwise (without giving some thought to it)

Comment: Hehe, no problem for me as I always stay updated, but thought it was okay to point out in case someone else would use the same solution at a later point running an older version of PHP:)

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution for **PHP 5.3+ only**:

```
class Toto {
    function __construct() {
        // list of classes that can extend Toto, including itself obviously:
        if(!in_array(get_called_class(), array(__CLASS__, 'Foo')))
            exit(get_called_class() . " cannot extend " . __CLASS__ . "\n");

        echo "Success\n";
    }
}

class Foo extends Toto {}
class Bar extends Toto {}

new Toto;
new Foo;
new Bar;
```

Which returns:

> Success
>   Success
>   Bar cannot extend Toto

**NB: this does *not* work if the constructor is overwritten.**

Comment: What if the list needs to be dynamic?

Comment: Just make it a property of the class.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is possible. Each class can be extended by any other class.

If you want to limit the classes that extend your abstract class you can make a final method with a whitelist in it. I think this is a dirty but acceptable solution.

Beware that you're working with people who consider themselves to be professional developers. If they are, they should read documentation. It is impossible to prevent them from making mistakes like this. If they don't read documentation they can just open your abstract class and simply add their class to the whitelist. Conclusion: This is not something you should handle in your code, but in the discipline of your colleagues.

Comment: You got a good point there pointing out that writing dirty cod might not be the best solution here. Having strickter guidelines might be a better solution, Thanks for you answer, all views on this is good. Was curious as to how it could be done codewise, but the discussion if it's good practice or not is just as important +1

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use database to accomplish this.

put `class name` the list of its `extendable class` in a row like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Class       |       Extendable class
-------------------------------------------------------------------
child 1     |       parent1,parent2,parent3
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then use this data in your code to see if a certain class is extendable

***May be a sample will be this***

```
$extendableClass = explode(',',$datarow['extendable class']);
$toextendClass = "parent4";
if(in_array($toextendClass,$extendableClass)) {
    //extend
}
else { 
    //dont extend
}
```

you can also use plain file or xml to store the class name instead of database or storing them in `multidimensional-array` might also get this done....

Comment: but this does not limit you not to extend a certan class eg. if after the if i do "Class Extended exteds NotExtendableClass" , it would work with no errors/exceptions thrown .

Comment: How does `Class Extended extends NotExtendableClass` work... that is main reason for checking whether the parent is extendable or not